# How to remove event listener in Ember

Tags: ember.js, addeventlistener

I would like to set up an event listener in a component on keydown event in Ember. The event listener gets properly added, but I can't seem to remove it as the removeEventListener passes in a different function. Any help on how to properly set this up would be appreciated.

```
onEscPress(e) {
  if (e.which === 27) {
    alert('test');
    this.send('dismissModal');
  }
},

willInsertElement() {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', this.onEscPress(e), false);
},

willDestroyElement() {
  // Uses a different function, so doesn't properly remove the listener
  window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.onEscPress(e), false);
},
```

Comment: The handler being removed must be **exactly** the same object as the handler that was added. It also must be a function, not a function invocation.

Comment: I believe fixing it to `this.onEscPress` should solve the problem.

Comment: I reproduce the problem [in a Twiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078190/how-to-remove-event-listener-in-ember).

Comment: Ditto, you are passing in `undefined` into the add/remove event listener (the result of calling your function)

Answer (score 8):

Its important to understand that in your code you passed the *result* of onEscPress to the event handler. This is *not* what you want.

Also you can't directly pass the function to the event handler if you want to use `this`, because it will be executed in a different dynamic context. So the correct way to do this is to

1. create a bound version of your function in the `init` hook,
2. add an event listener to that bound function in the `didInsertElement` hook, and
3. remove this bound function in the `willDestroyElement`hook.

So here is some code:

```
onEscPress(e) {
    if (e.which === 27) {
        alert('test');
        this.send('dismissModal');
    }
},
init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('boundOnEscPress', this.get('onEscPress').bind(this));
},
willInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.get('boundOnEscPress'), false);
},
willDestroyElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.get('boundOnEscPress'), false);
},
```

Also *never* forget calling `this._super(...arguments);`! Its *really* important!